# Is there a way to have both grayscale and rgb pixels on the same image opencv C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to be able to work with images where some regions are grayscale while others are kept on the RGB format. I don't want to convert an image into a grayscale since it will lose the channels and will become simply one channeled, is there a way to keep the RGB channels of some pixels on the picture and turn the others into a grayscale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO.

I see two solutions to this:

1. Have both a gray (`Mat1b`) and a rgb (`Mat3b`) image, and work on the image you need.
2. Have a single rgb (`Mat3b`) image, and set r,g,b channels to the same gray value where you need. In this way you can mimic to have a mixed gray/rgb image.