# Drawing a colored rectangle in a grayscale image using opencv

Tags: opencv

Is it possible to draw a colored rectangle in a grayscale image using opencv.
I tried several ways but either the whole image turns grayscale or RGB.

Comment: What about drawing a grayscale rectangle? is it possible to draw a single-channel-colored rectangle or other geometric shape?

Answer (score 9):

You can't have a mixed gray and color image. You can have a look at [Is there a way to have both grayscale and rgb pixels on the same image opencv C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31167490/5008845).

So you can't draw a colored rectangle on a grayscale `CV_8UC1` image. But you can draw it on a `CV_8UC3` image that shows your gray image.

You can create a `CV_8UC3` *gray-colored* image with `cvtColor(..., ..., COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`, and then you can draw your colored rectangle on it, e.g:

[image]

Note that this image, however, is no more of type `CV_8UC1`, but `CV_8UC3` instead.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b gray = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Convert gray image to BGR
    Mat3b grayBGR;
    cvtColor(gray, grayBGR, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    // Draw the colored rectangle
    rectangle(grayBGR, Rect(10, 10, 100, 200), Scalar(0,255,0), 2);

    imshow("Image with Rect", grayBGR);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @miki that worked for me. But the same didn't work for IplImage as it does for Mat format :(

Comment: Don't use iplimages. They are obsolete C syntax and shouldn't be use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. A grayscale image will be stored internally as one channel per pixel.
What you must do is convert the image to colour (using red = green = blue = grey value). Then you can draw any colour into the grey background. But of course the entire image then becomes a colour image, it's very unlikely there's any support for greyscale images with small areas of colour.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Malcolm